# Parse error (=), for function with uses pattern matching for lists?

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

```
list (x:xs) = "this letter is " ++ [x] ++ " and " ++ function xs
    where  function [] = "Empty"
           function x:[] = "Singlet"
           function x:y:[] = "Double"
           function x:y:xs = "LARGE list!"
```

Any idea why this function will not work I'm getting

> parse error on input ‘=’

Comment: Are you trying to type this in to ghci?

Comment: No i typed this into a file exactly the way as shown above.Any idea why I'm getting this error?

Comment: I get "parse error in pattern: function" , which I think is because you need brackets, as in "function (x:[]) = "Singlet"

Comment: Also, "x:[]" is equivalent to "[x]", and "x:y:[]" is equivalent to "[x,y]"

Answer (score 8):

The error message I get is a bit different, but at least one thing that's wrong with the code is that it lacks parentheses around the various list patterns:

```
list (x:xs) = "this letter is " ++ [x] ++ " and " ++ function xs
    where function [] = "Empty"
          function (x:[]) = "Singlet"
          function (x:y:[]) = "Double"
          function (x:y:xs) = "LARGE list!"
```

This compiles and works:

```
> list "foo"
"this letter is f and Double"
> list "barbaz"
"this letter is b and LARGE list!"
```

It's incomplete, though, because it doesn't match empty lists.

A more complete, and perhaps also more idiomatic version would be something like this:

```
list :: String -> String
list [] = "the list is empty"
list (x:xs) = "this letter is " ++ [x] ++ " and " ++ function xs
    where function [] = "Empty"
          function [_] = "Singlet"
          function [_,_] = "Double"
          function (_:_:_) = "LARGE list!"
```

Answer (score 6):

The error you are seeing is because your code contains tab characters. Your editor is set to display tabs as four spaces, which makes its indentation *look* correct, while Haskell counts them as eight, giving

```
list (x:xs) = "this letter is " ++ [x] ++ " and " ++ function xs
    where  function [] = "Empty"
               function x:[] = "Singlet"
               function x:y:[] = "Double"
                   function x:y:xs = "LARGE list!"
```

This error is particularly insidious because stackoverflow markdown *also* interprets tab characters as four spaces, meaning your code looked correctly indented to *us* as well, and even copies and pastes that way. Fortunately it *is* possible to check via the edit button if you are careful.

Solution: Avoid using tabs in Haskell code unless you are *sure* how to avoid the pitfalls.  And if you are ever going to post code on stackoverflow, avoid them anyway.

(The other answer has explained some things that need correcting after fixing the indentation.)